# How to use jest-dom without Jest

Tags: typescript, react-testing-library, jest-dom

I have a question about extending Typescript interfaces.
Here is my situation:

I am using `expect` in my tests without Jest (I installed it separately and it works).

Now I want to use `jest-dom` to add the `expect` matchers for DOM. (they are super helpful and will make my tests easier to write).

I did the following to extend expect

```
import expect from 'expect'
import * as matchers from '@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers'

expect.extend(matchers)
```

This works and adds the matchers, but Typescript doesn't know about them.

I installed `@types/testing-library/jest-dom` But it didn't solve the issue.

Looking inside `@types/testing-library__jest-dom` I see that it extends the types of `jest` and not the standalone `expect`.

I tried adding a `expect.d.ts` with the following content:

```
import 'expect'

declare module 'expect' {
  export interface Matchers<R> {
    toBeInTheDOM(container?: HTMLElement | SVGElement): R
    // ... other methods
  }
}
```

But Typescript is still complaining.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is your package json? I tried doing that and I get: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in '/......../node_modules/stack-utils'` and also `picomatch/lib` missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the following works

```
import 'expect/build/types'

declare module 'expect/build/types' {
  export interface Matchers<R> {
    // matchers methods here
  }
}
```