# How to use jest-dom as standalone in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs, testing-library, jest-dom

I want to use/run [jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom) matchers separately/standalone (not in a test, but in a webpage) like this:

```
import matchers from '@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers'
window.matchers = matches
```

This is what [jest-dom GitHub claims](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#inspiration):

> The intention is to make this available to be used independently of
> these other libraries, and also to make it more clear that these other
> libraries are independent from jest, and can be used with other tests
> runners as well.

[Btw, this is why I want to do it.](https://medium.com/codex/the-testing-library-meets-selenium-5f74cc712114?source=user_profile---------0----------------------------)

Then I run `webpack` command and load the auto-generated JS file (at `dist`) into a page.

Finally, in the page, I run this:

```
console.log(matchers.toBeDisabled(someElem))
```

it works perfectly. however, as soon as I run a matcher that receives an arg, it fails. e.g.:

```
console.log(matchers.toHaveAccessibleName(someElem, "name 1"))
```

it fails with:

```
this.equals is not a function
```

after hours of reading, I understand the reason. that function is provided by Jest's `expect` package and it's passed as context. ok, but how can I have it available?

[There's a similar question but it's a TypeScript error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65012078/how-to-use-jest-dom-without-jest)

Comment: Have you tried using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)?

Comment: as soon as I use bind or call to change context (e.g. `jsDomInvocation.bind({equals: () => {throw Error("abc")} })()`), I get the same: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'matcherHint')`

Comment: I meant more like `const toHaveAccessibleName = matchers.toHaveAccessibleName.bind(matchers)`.

Comment: I tried but got the same result. I believe `this.equals` is not present at all. even if the bind was correct, I'm not sure if its code exists at all because it belongs to jest and I only have jest-dom. so first I have to find out how to bring jest functions that matter in.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { expect } from 'expect'
import TestingLibraryMatchers from '@testing-library/dom/matchers.js'

expect.extend(TestingLibraryMatchers)

globalThis.expect = expect
```

Bundle this as an ESM or IIFE and then you can use it like

```js
expect(someElement).toBeDisabled()
```

Comment: what are the libs that I should have in `package.json`? besides `@testing-library/jest-dom`

Comment: `expect` is required. The dependencies are resolved by npm/yarn/your-package-manager

Comment: I get that: https://ctrl.vi/i/Dhu57D3xH
(and a lot of other fails before)

Comment: If you want to use the bundle in a browser, you need to replace the NodeJS core modules with polyfills.

Comment: any hint on how to do that? the weird thing is that I can use jest-dom but just the matches that receive no arguments.

Comment: these don't seem node.js libs; they seem jest related
https://justpaste.it/bb54q